# Getting rid of goto without duplication in Go

Tags: error-handling, go

Consider the following function:

```
func Listen(username string) (net.Listener, error) {
    path := filepath.Join(socketsDir, username)

    oldUmask := syscall.Umask(^0600)
    defer syscall.Umask(oldUmask)

    listener, err := net.Listen("unixpacket", path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    passwd, err := passwd.Getpwnam(username)
    if err != nil {
        goto chownFailed
    }

    err = os.Chown(path, int(passwd.Uid), os.Getgid())
    if err != nil {
        goto chownFailed
    }

    return listener, err

chownFailed:
    listener.Close()
    return nil, err
}
```

I think this way of error handling is ugly. Is there a way to get rid of the goto without duplicating the call to `listener.Close`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [defer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) along with named return values.

E.g.:

```
listener, err := net.Listen("unixpacket", path)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer func() {
    if err != nil {
        listener.Close()
    }
}()

// rest of function that just does "return nil, err" as needed
```

A runnable playground version of this:
https://play.golang.org/p/lKnGyzbp_3

Note, normally you'll see things like this in Go:

```
f, err := os.Open("somefile")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer f.Close()
```

That is easier and works for the common case where the thing (a file here) is being used just inside the function itself and needs to *always* be closed before returning to the caller. In the question however, the listening socket needs to be closed *only if there is a error after it was opened*. If there is no error it needs to be left open and returned to the caller. That's why the defer'ed function checks `err` (which it can do as long as it's a named returned value; you can even change named return values in a defer'ed function).

Comment: You don't need an closure there though. Just `defer listener.Close()` suffices.

Comment: @Ainar-G err, no?

Comment: @райтфолд What do you mean? The error from `net.Listen` has already been checked before, so you don't need to check `err` inside the deferred function.

Comment: @Ainar-G no you can't (a simple `defer` is what I had originally answered until I read the question more closely). If an error doesn't occur an _open_ listener needs to be returned. Always defering close is for things you are just using in the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

That's the standard C cleanup block, which is extremely widely used, you can see tons of examples just browsing the Linux kernel code. In more structured programming languages you have two (other) options:

- You can use a `try..finally` block. Simply return `nil` or the proper pair and `finally` will trigger either way to do cleanup. This is the equivalent of C#'s `using`, which I consider to be very graceful and semantic code. In Windows using SEH, such a block is pretty much free in terms of performance, only actually throwing and stack unwinding takes time.
- You can also define a lambda function at the beginning called `cleanup()` (or just `fail()`) and call it when appropriate. I consider this to be less elegant because if you forget to call it you'll have a leak.

Alternatively redesign your code to use RIAA. Go is a scoping language right? Like C++? Simply wrap your objects in a class and rely on destructors for cleanup.

Comment: your "answer" irrelevant to this question since the question is all about Go. Go doesn't have `try…finally` and it doesn't have destructors (it's garbage collected, it does have finalizers but they are inappropriate here).